# Angular 2 single line calendar

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives

Does anyone know if an Angular 2 single line calendar exists, is being developed or how to create one by manipulating an existing calendar? I can only find standard calendars as of the time of this post.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean _Single line calendar_? Like write one line of code, or the view is one line like a week, or something else

Comment: The view of the calendar could be one month/week/day on one line. I know I can reformat an existing calendar. What I am curious about is if there is a calendar that has been developed as a single line calendar that would be supported by Angular2.

Comment: Asking for recommendations or for the existence of such a component is [off-topic](/help/on-topic) on Stack Overflow. If you can edit your question to show what you've done to try and build it yourself, we can help clear any hurdles you might encounter. If you are looking for recommendations, check the [help center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help) of [softwarerecs.se] to see if your question could be made on topic there.